# Best way to convert ArrayList to string

Tags: java, string, arraylist

I have a scenario in which if the user select any option from drop-down then that value is going to server as `ArrayList`. And if the user does not select anything then the default value is going to server as String.  In java I have to convert the value to string(if i get `ArrayList` I have to convert that into string if i get string I have to store as it is. What is the best way to do this with minimal code?

I am trying below code :

```
String encoding =  myMap.get("encoding").toString();

encoding = encoding.replaceAll("\\[\\]", ""); \\removing brackets
```

Comment: Since you mention a server, use a simple and common syntax, [JSON](http://www.json.org/)

Comment: What is the structure of the option dropdown data

Comment: what i am doing is right?

Comment: encoding.replaceAll("\\[\\]", "") will replace brackets only if they are adjacent i.e. "[]". Try encoding.replaceAll("\\[", "").replaceAll("\\]", ""). But if your options contain "[" and/or "]" the results will not be as expected.

Comment: i am getting data as "abc" (string) sometime sometime as xyz(arraylist) only one element in arraylist

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the regex you're currently using, use `[\\[\\]]`.

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5);
String s = list.toString().replaceAll("[\\[\\]]", "");
System.out.println(s);
```

Or you can use `substring`, like

```
String s = list.toString().substring(1, list.toString().length()-1);
```

Comment: Is there any best way to handle it.  Instead of converting arraylist to string and then removing the braces.

Comment: @ramya you could also use substring, which might be faster, but most of the time, it won't make any difference.

Comment: Arraylist will have only one element always

Comment: @ramya then you could just do `list.get(0)`

Comment: i am getting in map and the value of map is arraylist  String encoding =  myMap.get("encoding").toString();

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to check if object converted to string is or is not array,because they are converted to string differently:

```
public String listToString(List<Object> list) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for (Object object : list) {
            if (object != null) {
                if (object.getClass().isArray()) {
                    sb.append(Arrays.toString((Object[]) object));
                } else {
                    sb.append(object.toString());
                }
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should never ever rely on things like `list.toString().replaceAll("[\\[\\]]", "")` because they are just an specific implementation of the toString method for the list and can be changed any moment making your code to crash...

Using ***join*** since java8

```
List<Object> olist = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
List<String> sList = olist.stream().map(String::valueOf).collect(Collectors.toList());
String results = String.join(",", sList);
System.out.println(results);
```

Comment: i have a map and the value of map may be either arralylist which has only one element or a string. What i am doing now is getting the value from the map(it may be arraylist with one element or a string) and converting it into string using Tostring then removing the bracket    String encoding =  myMap.get("encoding").toString();